# Organization/Individual Contact relationship

Tags: contacts, profile, upgrade

- I'm using CiviCRM as Joomla component
- Joomla users are not connected to CiviCRM contacts
- There are Organizations and Individual contacts
- Each Individual contact belong to Organization (employer) and has a specific group eg "Representative", "Librarian" etc.

## Updating profile info:

Organizations get an email (through mailing functionality) with personalized URL to update their profile fields.

## PROBLEM:

What is the best way to enable Organizations admin to update/add/delete Individual contacts which belong to that specific organization?

Comment: Are you saying "Joomla users are not connected to CiviCRM contacts" because this is how you want it to be, or that this is how it is but it is incorrect?

Comment: Thank for feedback!  
  
Well, I would like to avoid messing with Joomla ACL  
  
Scenario would be:  
1. create mailing to Organization (employer) email  
2. Employer contact gets personalized URL with a list of employees  
 (like the profile update link)  
3. Each employee record on that list has an "View/Update" button  
4. Click on Update opens profile form of that employee

Answer (score 2):

afaik there is nothing in civicrm that delivers quite what you ask.

The closest 'in the box' is probably the 'contact dashboard' which does let Primary Contact edit the Organisation record, and if you "allow second degree relationship permissions" [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1) the if Primary Contact has permission over the ORganisation and the Organisation has permissioned relationship over the other employees, then Primary contact can edit those people.

Of course the Primary Contact needs a joomla record to login to do this